# Rename Dom child node in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am working on DOM elements .
I am able to rename the root node but i also want to rename the child nodes :
Example:

```
<outcomes> to <ul> `
<para>     to <p>
```

This is so far :

Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();

```
         // Create an element with the new name
            Element element2 = doc.createElement("topic");

         // Copy the attributes to the new element
            NamedNodeMap attrs = element.getAttributes();
            for (int i=0; i<attrs.getLength(); i++) {
                Attr attr2 = (Attr)doc.importNode(attrs.item(i), true);
                element2.getAttributes().setNamedItem(attr2);
           }

         // Move all the children
            while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
                element2.appendChild(element.getFirstChild());
            }

            // Replace the old node with the new node
            element.getParentNode().replaceChild(element2, element);
```

:
It renames the root node but i want to rename the child nodes too 
I am using Java

Is there any easy and specific way to rename these child nodes

Thanx

Comment: lol, after posting your question, you should at least see at it for once, if it is published all right. BTW http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: <code>
while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
                    element2.appendChild(element.getFirstChild());
                }

                // Replace the old node with the new node
                element.getParentNode().replaceChild(element2, element);<code>

Answer (score 3):

The method for this is in a kind of obscure location: [Document.renameNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#renameNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Can you give me some specific code for doing this .
Thanx  ..  as i am new

Comment: Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
                
             // Create an element with the new name
                Element element2 = doc.createElement("topic");
while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
                    element2.appendChild(element.getFirstChild());
                }

                // Replace the old node with the new node
                element.getParentNode().replaceChild(element2, element);

Comment: @user1486269 - okay, so just add the rename call into the code where you are moving the children.